# Which native programming language is Flutter's code compile to?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, flutter-web

Using the Dart language allows Flutter to compile the source code ahead-of-time to native code.

I want to know which native language is it compiled to for different platforms.

Android- Is it Java or Kotlin?

iOS - Is it swift or objective c?

Web - is it Javascript or angular?

I can find everywhere that it's compiled to native code but couldn't find exactly which native programming language it is compiled to!

Comment: Did you not see: https://docs.flutter.dev/resources/architectural-overview

Comment: @Morrison Chang it mentions the language embedder is written into..Java and C++ for Android, Objective-C/Objective-C++ for iOS and macOS, and C++ for Windows and Linux.It doesn't says that application is compiled into this code?not sure if it means same but I have posted that part as an answer

Comment: `For release, Flutter apps are compiled directly to machine code, whether Intel x64 or ARM instructions, or to JavaScript if targeting the web.` from the link. The embedder is the interface to the platform (Android/iOS/desktop) framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Except for the web, where Dart is *transpiled* to JavaScript, Dart is not transpiled to another human-readable programming language.  For debug builds, Dart is compiled to Dart bytecode run through the Dart VM.  For release builds, it's compiled to "native code", which means it's machine code for the hardware (e.g. ARM instructions or x86-64 instructions).

Answer (score 1):

Actually when you create new flutter project from android studio, you can choose one of android and ios language:

android: java or kotlin

and

ios: objective-C or switft

this is my screenshot when i create new flutter project in android studio:
[image: image_screenshot]

Comment: Okay..and for web?

Comment: And here asking for language means that flutter code will be complied into selected language for respective platform?

Comment: Using a combination of DOM, Canvas, and WebAssembly, Flutter can provide a portable, high-quality, and performant user experience across modern browsers.

here is the full infomation about the flutter web: https://docs.flutter.dev/web

Comment: It should be noted that the language you specify in this dialog is not the language your application is compiled into. It is rather the language for native extensions you want to make in case you need to have deeper interaction with the OS. Your Dart code is compiled directly to assembly instructions for the target architecture when you are doing native programming, and JavaScript in case of web application.